# Intersection of a line in 3D and polygonal mesh

Tags: algorithm, 3d, mesh

I'm looking for a way to comput the intersection points of a line with a polygonal mesh in a 3D space.
I couldn't find an algorithm that does that.
Is there a simple algorithm (pseudo code) that returns the intersection points?

Answer (score 0):

Just test the intersection of the line with each face of the mesh. If your mesh has a large number of faces, you may want to use something like an octree or kd-tree to speed this process up.